# C++ assembly code analysis (compiled with clang)

Tags: c++, binary, clang

I am trying to figure out how the C++ binary code looks like, especially for virtual function calls. I have come up with few curious things. I have this following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
 public:
  virtual void print() { cout << "from base" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
 public:
  virtual void print() { cout << "from derived" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  Base *b;
  Derived d;
  d.print();
  b = &d;
  b->print();
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with clang++, and then use objdump:

```
00000000004008b0 <main>:
  4008b0:   55                      push   rbp
  4008b1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
  4008b4:   48 83 ec 20             sub    rsp,0x20
  4008b8:   48 8d 7d e8             lea    rdi,[rbp-0x18]
  4008bc:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
  4008c3:   e8 28 00 00 00          call   4008f0 <Derived::Derived()>
  4008c8:   48 8d 7d e8             lea    rdi,[rbp-0x18]
  4008cc:   e8 5f 00 00 00          call   400930 <Derived::print()>
  4008d1:   48 8d 7d e8             lea    rdi,[rbp-0x18]
  4008d5:   48 89 7d f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rdi
  4008d9:   48 8b 7d f0             mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
  4008dd:   48 8b 07                mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rdi]
  4008e0:   ff 10                   call   QWORD PTR [rax]
  4008e2:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  4008e4:   48 83 c4 20             add    rsp,0x20
  4008e8:   5d                      pop    rbp
  4008e9:   c3                      ret    
  4008ea:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

My question is why in assembly code, we have the following code:

```
  4008b8:   48 8d 7d e8             lea    rdi,[rbp-0x18]
  4008d1:   48 8d 7d e8             lea    rdi,[rbp-0x18]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local variable `d` in `main()` is stored at location `[rbp-0x18]`.  This is in the automatic storage allocated on the stack for `main()`.

```
lea    rdi,[rbp-0x18]
```

This line loads the address of `d` into the `rdi` register.  By convention, member functions of `Derived` treat `rdi` as the `this` pointer.

Comment: the `rdi` register have not used here (4008b8, 4008c8), then why it loads?

Comment: The register is used inside the functions `Derived::Derived()` (at 4008c3), and `Derived::print()` at 4008cc.  `Derived::Derived()` constructs the vptr at `[rdi]`, and `Derived::print()` doesn't use rdi, but it could if it needed to reference the `this` pointer.